# Is there any way to change order note color in admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I need a help , is there any way to change order note color in admin panel [wordpress-woocommerce].
for example green color for "Order status changed from Processing to Confirmed." yellow color for "Order status changed from Pending Payment to Processing."

Is there any hook available ? Please reply .

It is not about the status icon or status color . It is about the order notes .
for example it is about the --> "Order status changed from Processing to Confirmed.
added on December 29, 2015 at 11:22 AM
Delete note" in single order detailed page(wp-admin/post.php?post=12345&action=edit).

not about the status icon example green icon for confirmed order in order list page(wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no hook available in woocommerce for doing that .

Answer (score 2):

Woocommerce introduce 'woocommerce_order_note_class' filter for to solve this . See this answer https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-there-any-way-to-change-order-note-color-in-admin-panel

Comment: I have wrote a simple plugin based on my reply in above link. So you can [use this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/colored-order-notes-for-woocommerce/) directly :-)

Comment: Good one  .Thank you

Comment: Hi, could you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526268/sql-query-to-download-order-report-in-woocommerce  .  I have the same situation .