# Sql query to download order report in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

please help to complete this. I need to download order report of woocommerce  in csv format, for that i made the following query:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Date', 'Status','Name'));
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT ID,post_date,post_status,post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date LIKE "%2016-03-30%"');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

And this is just a trail and here i only fetch data from post table.

But i need to connect to *postmeta* and other tables, so that i can get all information about order.
By searching on the internet i get the following code, but i don't know how to integrate with this with my code.
 
See the query for to get all order details:

```
select
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_address_1,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_2' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_address_2,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_city,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_state,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_postcode,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_last_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_address_1,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_2' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_address_2,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_city' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_city,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_state,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_postcode,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_tax,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_paid_date' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as paid_date,
    ( select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
from
    wp_posts as p,
    wp_postmeta as pm
where
    post_type = 'shop_order' and
    p.ID = pm.post_id and
    post_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-07-08'
    and post_status = 'wc-completed'
group by
    p.ID
```

Please help to complete this, or is there any good method rather than this?
I don't want to use plugins.
 
Currently i have a plugin, but that is working slow, that's why i making this page.

Please help to solve this issue .

Comment: Hey @Manik, can you provide more of a description for the part your stuck on? Don't believe a full solution for your problem can be solved in one post, but perhaps you can show exactly where the disconnect is. I see you have a SQL statement, does this currently give the correct results and you just need this statement in a custom WordPress query?

Comment: Could you please give the wp_query to fetch data and please tell me  how to make download in csv . It will really help to me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own [blog post](https://igotaprinter.com/blog/exporting-customer-information-from-woocommerce.html), this is the format for the SQL to extract information from an EAV style table layout.

```
$reportQuery = "
SELECT
  A.ID as order_id
, B.meta_value as b_first_name
, C.meta_value as b_last_name
, D.meta_value as b_address_1
, E.meta_value as b_address_2
, F.meta_value as b_country
, G.meta_value as b_state
, H.meta_value as b_city
, I.meta_value as b_postcode
, J.meta_value as b_user_id
, K.user_email as b_email

FROM wp_posts as A
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta B 
  ON A.id = B.post_id AND B.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta C
  ON A.id = C.post_id AND C.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta D
  ON A.id = D.post_id AND D.meta_key = '_billing_address_1'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta E
  ON A.id = E.post_id AND E.meta_key = '_billing_address_2'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta F
  ON A.id = F.post_id AND F.meta_key = '_billing_country'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta G
  ON A.id = G.post_id AND G.meta_key = '_billing_state'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta H
  ON A.id = H.post_id AND H.meta_key = '_billing_city'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta I
  ON A.id = I.post_id AND I.meta_key = '_billing_postcode'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta J
  ON A.id = J.post_id AND J.meta_key = '_customer_user'

LEFT JOIN wp_users K
  ON J.meta_value = K.ID

WHERE A.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND   A.post_status = 'wc-completed';
AND   A.post_date_gmt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
";

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=woocommerce-'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$rows = mysql_query($reportQuery);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
fclose($output);
```

Comment: sorry for the late response . Thank you :)

Comment: could you please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505056/woocommerce-create-new-discount-functionality